# How do I save an attachment to a local folder in VMware Boxer email client?

Tags: email, vmware

I have recently begun using VMware Boxer email client for Android.  I received a PDF attachment to an email.  When trying to download it, I am given only two options: "Open in" and "Save in Boxer."  When I save the file in Boxer, it is not visible anywhere except in the Boxer file browser.  I have looked through the directory structure with another file browser, but I do not see where the file is stored on my phone or even where Boxer stores its data.  Does anyone know how I can simply save the PDF into my "Downloads" directory and not be stuck with it within Boxer.  I had been using Outlook, and it by default just stores the downloaded file in the public downloads directory.

Comment: I don't know Boxer in detail but as it is focused on business users it might be a security feature that attachments stay in the VMWare Boxer "container" so other apps can not steal the data. Is your mail account managed or a regular IMAP account?

Comment: It is synced through Exchange.  It is locally managed.  Hope that answers the question.